# Read variables like credentials from server file

Tags: bash, credentials

This is my first post, and actually first steps into bash.
I wanted to create automated ftp server backup feature to make my life easier. Since I've felt good doing this script I've started working on improvements for it and currently I ran out of ideas.
I wanted to make script backup download all files from ftp server and defined credentials as variables (which I am proud of lol) but then I've realized that I can use same script for all my servers but I will have to store login credentials in separate file.
The problem is that I can't make my script to read this values for backup processing and they remain blank as I see from output.
If anyone have any ideas how can I make it read my credentials and server name from separate file I would be grateful!
Below you can find my files and scripts in order that they are being processed:

**'start_backup.sh'**

```
#!/bin/sh  
# Load credentials
/home/user/scripts/credentials.sh

# Launch backup script
/home/user/scripts/my_ovh_backup.sh
```

**credentials.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
my_ovh_server="(server address goes here)"
my_ovh_login="(login goes here)"
my_ovh_password="(password goes here)"
```

**my_ovh_backup.sh**

```
# Path that need to be copied
backup_files="/(path on server)"

# Where to backup
dest="/home/user/ftp_backup"
data=$(date +%y-%m-%d)

# Create folder with current date
mkdir $dest/in_progress_$data

# Copy data
cd $dest/in_progress_$data
wget -r -nc ftp://$my_ovh_login:$my_ovh_password@$my_ovh_server/$backup_files

# Rename folder after download completion
mv $dest/in_progress_$data $dest/$data

# Cleanup
rm -r $dest/$data
```

Output that I recieve:

```
./start_backup.sh 
ftp://:@//(remote folder)/: Invalid host name.
adding: home/user/ftp_backup/22-01-02/ (stored 0%)
```

Comment: Look at the bash `source` command to pull the variables from one script into another -i.e. `source /home/user/scripts/credentials.sh`

Comment: You mention it is an automated backupscript, so i'm guessing you're letting it run at certain intervals using a cronjob or systemd ? If your system has systemd, then i'd recommend using a systemd.timer unit to start your script at specific times, and using `EnvironmentFile=` for the credentials. That way they can be safely stored away and they'll be available to your script as environment variables. (so the very first line in your script could be `echo $my_ovh_server;` and it'd print the username).

Comment: @Raxi yes, it will end up in cron. Should I place 'EnironmentFile=' in cron?

Comment: No it's a systemd feature; i don't know if your system uses that or not ? most do nowadays. If it does you'd have to write a (very short) `.service` unit for your script (which tells systemd how to run it, and includes the `EnvironmentFile=`). And then a `.timer` unit which tells systemd when to automatically run the script (that part replaces the cronjob altogether) -- Both unit files can be really tiny and simple (for example: https://documentation.suse.com/smart/linux/html/task-create-systemd-timers/index.html#id-1.5 )

Comment: @match you are right. I had to google around because for some reason my Ubuntu didn't red source command properly, I had to use dot instead.

Comment: @Raxi thank you for sharing this. I see great potential in this and I need to read more about services and so on and at some stage of improving my script I will use it! Thank you all guys!